# Can instanceof operator be used to test any value type?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Is it safe to use instanceof operator to test any value type?

E.g.

```
(x instanceof Object) // x is defined, but can be anything, including undefined)
```

Should we ever expect an error thrown here in any browser / js engine?

Comment: Do you mean does it ever throw an error?

Comment: Yes, I corrected the question.

Comment: I don’t think it can. Try testing the instance of a variable which hasn’t been defined?

Comment: I have tested all types in the chrome dev tools. However, that's only one environment.  I wonder if it happens to be a standard.

Comment: Maybe. Have you tried in Firefox?